# Is there a macro definition to check the Linux kernel version?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, macros, linux-kernel

I'm wondering if there is a gcc macro that will tell me the Linux kernel version so I can set variable types appropriately. If not, how would I go about defining my own macro that does this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The **linux/version.h** file has a macro called `KERNEL_VERSION` which will let you check the version you want against the current linux headers version (`LINUX_VERSION_CODE`) installed. For example to check if the current Linux headers are for kernel *v2.6.16* or earlier:

```
#include <linux/version.h>

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,16)
...
#else
...
#endif
```

A better way to get the version information at run-time is to use the `utsname` function in [include/linux/utsname.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/utsname.h).

```
char *my_kernel_version = utsname()->release;
```

This is essentially how `/proc/version` gets the current kernel verison.

#### See also

> [Getting kernel version from linux kernel module at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8030951/1806289)

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` won't know this information.  As an alternative, you can determine a lot of kernel information at runtime easily.

You can define your runtime type like

```
struct unified_foo {
     unsigned int kernel_version;
     union {
         kernel_x_foo_type k_x;
         kernel_y_foo_type k_y;
         kernel_z_foo_type k_z;
     } u;
};
```

and have code at runtime look at `/proc/version` (or whatever you need from the kernel runtime environment) and set `kernel_version` approriately.  The `kernel_x_foo_type` et al. is your type that you want to be conditional on the kernel version.  The calling code needs to look at `kernel_version` and access the appropriate `u.k_x`, `u.k_y`, or `u.k_z` data.

Comment: is there another way for me to have different variable types based on kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

In kernel code first Makefile. You will find version-related variables.

```
VERSION = 4
PATCHLEVEL = 9
SUBLEVEL = 37
```