# Get kernel version | Linux kernel API

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Searching kernel sources and can't locate any method which returns kernel version neither integral nor string. Does Linux kernel API has this one?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `cat /proc/version` ?

Comment: @Alex Again, I'm searching for method of Linux kernel API. I want to use it in some kernel module.

Comment: From within a module that's something you normally check at compile time, not via an API call.

Comment: Look into: `/usr/include/linux/version.h`, `${src}/init/version.c`, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721346/linux-kernel-version-macro-definition. have a look at the explainations there how to get the stuff at compile/run time.

Comment: @Alex You're definitely right.

Comment: If you need current kernel in the system, try to use "uname -a" command.

Comment: run "uname -r" in terminal