# Linux Kernel Patch Version Macro Definition

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, macros, preprocessor

I'd like to build my kernel modules for centos 7 kernels. But I have problem with some function prototype. It's different in kernel-3.10.0-**327.36.3.el7** and kernel-3.10.0-**514.el7**. I know how to use [Linux Kernel Version Macro Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721346/linux-kernel-version-macro-definition). But I need to check kernel Patch Version and linux directory name.

Some body know preprocessor macro for checking kernel's patch version?

Comment: For a quick reply, you can ask this question in IRC. https://kernelnewbies.org/IRC

Comment: Ok. If I solve this problem in kernelnewbies.org/IRC I tell to know here

Comment: I believe those extra numbers you get are added automatically if `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO` is set.
which corresponds to the source tree version.
check [this](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/LOCALVERSION_AUTO.html)

Comment: CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO - is another extra suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found some information. We can use some predefined variables from Makefile in kernel headers. For example in centos 7 we have kernel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7. There are variables in file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/Makefile:

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 10
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION = -514.16.1.el7.x86_64
NAME = Unicycling Gorilla
RHEL_MAJOR = 7
RHEL_MINOR = 3
RHEL_RELEASE = 514.16.1
...
```

In our Makefile for kernel module we can put it in our source code by -DPATCH_VERSION=${RHEL_RELEASE} gcc parametr(or example in centos 7). But need to check distro because in debian there isn't RHEL_RELEASE variable.

I think there is better way.