# Check linux kernel version in user space Android

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, android-build

I am porting a v4l2 driver from kernel 4.4 to 4.9. In 4.4 kernel, we are using type and group_id for enumerating media entity. But group_id is obsolete in kernel 4.9. I want to have same user space code for both kernel versions.

Is there any way to identify kernel version at compile time or run time. I will prefer to have compile time check.

[struct media_entity_desc](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/mediactl/media-ioc-enum-entities.html) This is same for both kernel versions, but on 4.9 group_id will always contains 0.

[struct media_entity on 4.9](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9.72/source/include/media/media-entity.h#L261)

[struct media_entity on 4.4](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4.108/source/include/media/media-entity.h#L63)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a macro definition to check the Linux kernel version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721346/is-there-a-macro-definition-to-check-the-linux-kernel-version)

Comment: @Tsyvarev [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721346/is-there-a-macro-definition-to-check-the-linux-kernel-version) does not allow me to differentiate b/w 4.4 and 4.9.

Comment: What exactly do you use? (The accepted answer suggests several approaches.) Why it don't help? Note, that macro LINUX_VERSION_CODE contains version of the kernel against which libc has been compiled, not the current kernel version.