# Adaptation from old init_timer to new timer_setup

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have been trying to port a driver from 2.6 to 4.X without support from the original board manufacturer (and very limited Linux experience).

The original driver uses `init_timer()` and passes in a pointer to the `timer_list` structure. That `timer_list` structure's `data` element was set to a pointer to another memory structure and the `function` element set to the callback.  Inside the callback function the `data` element was used to access other bits of stuff.

The current timer `init`-method uses:

```
timer_setup( timer_list *, callback, (unsigned int) flags);
```

and the `timer_list` structure was changed to eliminate the `data` field.

I'm not sure what is the best/proper way to inform the callback function of the equivalent `data` element.  Can anyone provide some guidance?

Here is a snippet of the old driver:

```
myDevice * dev;

dev->getIntrTimer = kmalloc(sizeof(struct timer_list), GFP_KERNEL);    
init_timer(dev->getIntrTimer);

dev->getIntrTimer->data = (unsigned long) dev;
dev->getIntrTimer->function = GetIntrTimerCallback;
```

The callback function starts off like this:

```
void GetIntrTimerCallback(unsigned long devAddr)
{
    myDevice *dev = (myDevice *) devAddr;
    dev->blahBlah++; // etc.
```

So the old code gets passed the pointer to `myDevice` so inside the callback that structure can be accessed.

But with the new timer method only has available an int that is 4 bytes but a pointer is 8 (or whatever).

What I'd like to do is this:

```
dev->getIntrTimer = kmalloc(sizeof(struct timer_list), GFP_KERNEL);
timer_setup(dev->getIntrTimer, GetIntrTimerCallback, dev);
```

but of course that generates compile errors because `dev` is a pointer to type `myDevice`, which does not fit in an int.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `timer_setup()` with three args is present since 4.14 Linux kernel (FYI there was `setup_timer()` in slightly earlier versions). If you maintain some code which should be relevant up to recent kernels - you have to change it in appropriate way every time the API changes. Now you can access your data through the special function `from_timer()` based on [`container_of()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-the-linux-kernel).

`timer_list` is normally used not as pointer inside struct, so the example implies normal usage and could be something like:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(4,14,0)
    init_timer(&dev->getIntrTimer);
    dev->getIntrTimer.data = (unsigned long) dev;
    dev->getIntrTimer.function = GetIntrTimerCallback;
    /* ... */
    add_timer(&dev->getIntrTimer);
#else
    timer_setup(&dev->getIntrTimer, GetIntrTimerCallback, 0);
    /* the third argument may include TIMER_* flags */
    /* ... */
#endif
```

---

The callback function:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(4,14,0)
void GetIntrTimerCallback(unsigned long devAddr)
{
    myDevice *dev = (myDevice *) devAddr;
#else
void GetIntrTimerCallback(struct timer_list *t)
{
    myDevice *dev = from_timer(dev, t, getIntrTimer);
#endif
    /* Do something with "dev" */
```

Read also:

- [Linux kernel timers new API](https://lwn.net/Articles/735887/)
- [Example](https://lwn.net/Articles/735892/)
- [Linux kernel versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721346/is-there-a-macro-definition-to-check-the-linux-kernel-version)

Comment: Yikes!  And timer_setup was supposed to be an improvement!?!

Comment: Anyway, I made the changes (apparently page_cache_release() and get_user_pages() have been similarly improved). But I get compile errors in the callback function with the from_timer() call.  

The error is "pointer type mismatch in container_of()".  Am I supposed to be casting any/all of those arguments? The error message doesn't give many clues (that I understand) on which argument is flagged.

Comment: @ElRonaldo Error messages about `container_of()` are quite reasonable if `timer_list` is declared as pointer in your struct. As mentioned above the example ***is not for case*** `typedef struct { struct timer_list *getIntrTimer; /*smth else*/ } myDevice;`, but ***is for case*** `typedef struct { struct timer_list getIntrTimer; /*smth else*/ } myDevice;`

Comment: Ohhhh, you mean I'm supposed to read your **whole** response!?!!??  I've too short an attention span for that, man!

Comment: Does from_timer  **require** that  struct timer_list be the first element in the myDevice struct?  In my case it is not only a pointer, but also not the first element, and frankly I do not follow the container_of() expansion.

Comment: =) It doesn't have to be the first element.

Comment: @ElRonaldo, new *timer_setup()* API is definitely an improvement.

Comment: Don't forget to add
    #include <linux/version.h>
to your code.