# Linux Kernel error: missing binary operator before token "("

Tags: c, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor, kernel-module

Some simple preprocessor code in Linux Kernel module gives the following error:

> missing binary operator before token "("

The code:

```
#if defined(AAA) || defined(BBB)

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(3,13,0)
#define SOME 111
#else
#define SOME 222
#endif

#define OTHER 999

#else

#define SOME 1
#define OTHER 9

#endif /* AAA || BBB */
```

[That post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338385/what-does-the-compiler-error-missing-binary-operator-before-token-mean) didn't help.

Comment: use `gcc -E` to figure out what it expands to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that error means KERNEL_VERSION is not defined

you missed to `#include <linux/version.h>`

---

*Edit*

About kernel version see also : [Is there a macro definition to check the Linux kernel version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721346/is-there-a-macro-definition-to-check-the-linux-kernel-version)