# Alternate old sys_close and new ksys_close on same module

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile my kernel module that uses "ksys_close" running on Linux-5.3. The issue comes when I want to compile the module on a different machine running Linux-4.15, where the "ksys_close" doesn't exist. So I have to use the old convention "sys_close" when the kernel is older than version 4.15.

More info: https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/937297/

How can I avoid changing my code every time?

I'm a noob on kernel module programming :)

Makefile:

```
obj-m += interceptor.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

linux-4.15

```c
if (sct[__NR_close] == (unsigned long *) sys_close)
    return sct;
```

linux-5.3

```c
if (sct[__NR_close] == (unsigned long *) ksys_close)
    return sct;
```

Error using "ksys_close" running Linux-4.15:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/build M=/root/module modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic'
  CC [M]  /root/module/interceptor.o
/root/module/interceptor.c: In function ‘aquire_sys_call_table’:
/root/module/interceptor.c:30:44: error: ‘ksys_close’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘sys_close’?
   if (sct[__NR_close] == (unsigned long *) ksys_close)
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
                                            sys_close
/root/module/interceptor.c:30:44: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/Makefile.build:337: recipe for target '/root/module/interceptor.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/root/module/interceptor.o] Error 1
Makefile:1562: recipe for target '_module_/root/module' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/root/module] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Isn't there a macro that gives you either the kernel version or a way to check for features? Then you could use an `#ifdef` with a `#define` to switch to whatever sys call you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721346/is-there-a-macro-definition-to-check-the-linux-kernel-version/16721774